# Calculate median income from binned census data

Tags: r

I have census data showing binned household income for a particular region:

```
test_data <- data.frame(region = "Pluto", 
                        low = c(1,7800,15600,20800,26000,33800,41600,52000,65000,78000,91000,104000,156000),
                        high = c(7799,15599,20799,25999,33799,41599,51999,64999,77999,90999,103999,155999,Inf),
                        households = c(10674,17768,20497,18413,17261,20529,24754,25286,16704,12847,8654,11170,3480)) 

test_data <- test_data %>% mutate(bin_interval = paste(low, high, sep = " - "))
```

"low" and "high" refer to bin edges. I want to estimate the median income for this region. To do this I need to fit a distribution to the binned data. From this distribution I can compute the median value. Can somebody show me how to do this? Many thanks in advance!

Note that I have many regions. The example data is for one region only.

Comment: Why do you need to fit a distribution to the data? Why not estimate the median from the data?

Comment: What is your expected output for given example ?

Comment: For region Pluto, the median income is $X per annum. Perhaps I am overthinking the problem but the packages binsmooth and binequality suggest that estimating a median value from data is fraught as it assumes data is uniformly spread across each class/bin. Moreover, there is no upper bound. These two packages do not have vignettes to explain things.

Comment: Since you have binned data any statistics are going to be dubious. Also, the distribution for Pluto is bimodal (or evn tri-), which further complicates things. I don't think your approach is going to work.

Comment: Thanks. Let me think about this more. I may just go with total income generated per region.